# Why can I not use these variables in my function?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

Ok I'm new to programming and currently figuring out javascript.

I know that my question has something to do with scope, but I'm looking to understand why it doesn't actually want to play ball.

I've made a basic "calculator" that adds two numbers together that the user enters in the input fields.

[See the code that works](http://codepen.io/tjlala/pen/xGyZrP?editors=101)

[The code that doesn't work](http://codepen.io/tjlala/pen/ZGqQJB?editors=101)

```
var numOne = document.getElementById('num-one');
var numTwo = document.getElementById('num-two');
var addSum = document.getElementById('add-sum');

//function to add 2 numbers enter into the elements
//declare function name
function add() {
    //set our function var's to manipulate
var one  = parseFloat(numOne.value) || 0;
var two =  parseFloat(numTwo.value) || 0; 
addSum.innerHTML = one + two;
```

My question is: why do I have to create method variables and not use the ones I have already declared?

Comment: First ones are variables for HTML element object and the second ones are for float values to do calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code that doesn't work:

```
//create a calculator to add 2 numbers together.

var numOne = document.getElementById('num-one');
var numTwo = document.getElementById('num-two');
var addSum = document.getElementById('add-sum');

// function to add 2 numbers enter into the elements
function add() {
    //set our function var's to manipulate
    numOne += parseFloat(numOne.value) || 0;
    numTwo +=  parseFloat(numTwo.value) || 0; 
    addSum.innerHTML = numOne + numTwo;
}

numOne.addEventListener("input", add);
numTwo.addEventListener("input", add);
```

This does not work because `numOne` is a DOM element so doing `+=` to a DOM element does not do what you want at all.  You don't want to be adding to the DOM element.  You want to be retrieving the element's `.value` property so you can use it in a calculation.  You can simplify your code like this working snippet:

```js
// create a calculator to add 2 numbers together.
var numOne = document.getElementById('num-one');
var numTwo = document.getElementById('num-two');
var addSum = document.getElementById('add-sum');

// function to add 2 numbers enter into the elements
function add() {
    //set our function var's to manipulate
    addSum.innerHTML = (parseFloat(numOne.value) || 0) + (parseFloat(numTwo.value) || 0);
}

numOne.addEventListener("input", add);
numTwo.addEventListener("input", add);
```

```css
p {
  line-height: 150%;
}
```

```html
<p>
Num One: <input id="num-one"><br>
Num Two: <input id="num-two"><br>
Sum: <span id="add-sum">0</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice- great explanation - should i be declaring the func before or after the execution. I see different people do different things.. and  declaring the function before execution makes more sense to me

Comment: Javascript doesn't care if you write the function before it's used, or after. The whole script get's parsed before it's run. So if you like putting the functions first, then that's the best answer for you :)

Comment: @ThomasJ - Function and variable definitions in Javascript are automatically "hoisted" to the top of whatever scope they are defined in when the script is parsed before it is run.  That means that it does not matter whether a function's definition comes before or after it is defined since all definitions within a scope will be known before the first line of code in that scope is actually executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the add() function somewhere.
Use of parseInt is to convert the variables to integers, to find some of there, otherwise concatenation of the variables will happen.

Comment: OK thanks and should my function be before or after I execute. Right now i've declared it before...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggested answer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function add(a, b) 
    {
        //set our function var's to manipulate
        a = parseFloat(a);
        b = parseFloat(b);
        return a + b;
    }

    function go() // do this in response to some event like form submit
    {
        var numOne = document.getElementById('num-one').value;
        var numTwo = document.getElementById('num-two').value;
        document.getElementById('add-sum').value = add(numOne, numTwo); // call the add function here
    }

</script>
```

Use function parameters. They make a function more reusable. And don't be afraid to use the function's return value. In this example, the `add()` function is not reliant on any external code or variables. As long as the correct parameters are passed to it, it will return an appropriate value. Note it doesn't attempt to do any error handling or type checking, but then this is a simple example.

Also, you don't need to store a variable for the 'add-sum' form field since you never read it's value. You can just get a reference to it to write the sum.

Finally, I've added the `go()` function which you should probably call as a result of some kind of event on your page, like form submit, or onChange in the input fields.